# LevelDB access problems

Tags: google-chrome-extension, leveldb

I'm trying to recover my lost data in chrome Extension "OneTab" 
The extension uses level DB to store the data 
I tried https://filext.com/file-extension/LDB
It opened partially the file and it seems to have the URL's 
I have a good reason to believe one of the .ldb files have the data 
But The encryption makes the file useless
So how can I decrypt the binaries and retrieve my data?

Comment: There are utilities that decode LevelDB files but usually you can simply install the extension, disable it, copy the entire directory with the data files, enable the extension.

Comment: I tried this but It didn't work, Chrome reinstalled the extension when it crashed, so I believe that's why it couldn't read the .ldb files. Something is corrupted

Comment: So can you tell me more about utilities to decode LevelDB files?

Comment: I haven't tried myself so try searching: [utility extract|decode|dump LevelDB files](https://www.google.com/search?q=utility+extract%7Cdecode%7Cdump+LevelDB+files).

Comment: It tried but couldn't use any tool, can I have some more details. I have no experience with DB at all